# How to use either array<int,10> or array<int,4> at runtime?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, stdarray

I want my code to use either a short version of an array, or a long version (with more elements in it) depending on a runtime value.

```
constexpr std::array<int, 10> longArray{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
constexpr std::array<int,4> shortArray{0,3,6,9};
auto const& myArray = useShortArray ? shortArray : longArray;
for( auto n : myArray ) {
     // Do the stuff
}
```

As above, there's an error because the arguments to the ternary operator are not the same.

How can I do this?

The only way is to declare two begin and end iterators that are assigned. But this leads to use the old `for` on iterators and requires to dereference the iterator at every use within the `for` block.

```
auto const& myBegin = useShortArray ? shortArray.begin() : longArray.begin();
auto const& myEnd   = useShortArray ? shortArray.end()   : longArray.end();
for( auto it = myBegin ; it != myEnd ; ++it ) {
    // use *it
}
```

Is there some way to write it (maybe copying the arrays to vectors?) to avoid reverting to the begin/end version?

Comment: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (C++20) might help (but it is mostly begin/end iterator, but as range).

Comment: You could try using an stl algorithm for `do the stuff`, in many cases there is something fitting. If in doubt, [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) will certainly work.

Comment: An alternative is `template <typename T> SomeType do_job(const T& array) {/*...*/}` and then `return useShortArray ? do_job(shortArray) : do_job(longArray);`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, even `auto begin = useShortArray ? shortArray.begin() : longArray.end()` works only by accident because `std::array<T, N>::iterator` type may depend on `N` (and it [does](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/098333c9126c4df2370b3d08f8800bb5e3d82f1e/stl/inc/array#L35) in MS STL).

Comment: *"How to use either array<int,9> or array<int,4>"* and then `constexpr std::array<int, 10> longArray` ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Then why not `constexpr std::array<int, 13> bothArrays`? :P

Comment: @PaulEvans: Because `13` is really `9+4`, so prefer other numbers as `42` ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a lambda for example:

```
auto doTheStuff = [](auto& myArray) {
    for(auto n : myArray) {
         // Do the stuff
    }
};

useShortArray ? doTheStuff(shortArray) : doTheStuff(longArray);
```

Alternatively, if you want to give it a name this can be a template function.

Another approach is to use a span, such as the upcoming `std::span` in C++20. In this approach the template function that accepts different sized arrays is the constructor of the span. This way the function that uses the range doesn't need to be a template.